# Sequencing distributed tasks with a distributed DB

Tags: database, distributed-computing, message-queue, data-replication

### Background

I have two separate processes, `WriteIt()` and `ReadIt()`.  One creates records, and the other processes the records in a DB cluster.

Once `WriteIt()` creates a record, it queues a `ReadIt()` task to process the same record.

To illustrate:

[image]

Unfortunately, the database write and replication takes an unreliable amount of time, so `ReadIt()` has to keep checking for the presence of the updated record, which seems quite inefficient.

---

### Question

This has got to be a common pattern for distributed systems.  So my questions are:

1. Is there a general term (or terms) for this pattern, so that I can read about how to solve it?  Unfortunately I don't even know what the right terminology is so I've had a heck of a time doing research on Google/SO/Programmers.SE.
2. (for extra credit) Is there an specific common approach to solving this issue with SQLAlchemy/MySQL and Celery?

I recognize that #2 is pretty specific, so I would be happy with just #1 since I just need to be pointed in the right direction to research the pattern.

Comment: Just curious: why don't you just pass the data to `ReadIt()` after inserting? It'd be much faster and reliable. If record needs to be updated by `ReadIt()` you can update it by ID or something.

Comment: @scriptin great question.  `ReadIt()` does a series of tasks which involve querying the DB for a family of records including the one just added.  It then does a group calculation across all of those records, so I'd like to make sure I'm doing these operations only after the new record is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically yes the name of the pattern in distributed systems is called **eventual consistency**.

The common approach is to **synchronously** write the data to an **event store** and then write to SQL. Your queued background read job can rest assured that once the data is in the event store, it's a success and won't be lost.

Usually people use a high-performance storage system that is very fast at handling and serialising a lot of concurrent writes for the event store.

A good approach is often called **command-query responsibility separation with event sourcing**.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great set of terms to get me going....exactly what I was looking for!  +1...will wait a couple days to accept the answer in case other responses trickle in, but thanks so much